# Por qué al enviar o recibir valores float desde PHP a base datos Oracle lo debo hacer con coma y la DB lo recibe con punto?

Tags: php, oracle, xampp, float, dll

Tengo una base de datos Oracle y un sitio en PHP en equipos distintos que se conecta a la misma para hacer consultas, insertar y modificar datos, me sucede que los datos con decimales los recibo al hacer una consulta con coma pero en la base de datos aparecen con punto, esto sucede en mi ambiente de pruebas que lo corro con XAMPP en windows, PHP 8 (verifique con distintas versiones y da el mismo resultado) y el la versión de Oracle es 10, en producción no sucede siento que es el DLL que hace la conexión pero no se si alguien mas le ha pasado y ver como se arregla para dejar mi ambiente de desarrollo igual que producción y que solo maneje punto en los decimales en lugar de coma.

Comment: Haz que tu título suene más _natural_ y agrega más detalles a tu pregunta, que podría terminar cerrada por ser demasiado amplia. Lee [ask].

Comment: ¿En qué sistema operativo esta el XAMPP? ¿Oracle esta en otro equipo?

Comment: gracias el Xampp está corriendo en Windows 10  y Oracle si está en otro equipo distinto. hago consultas desde toad y ahí si sale con punto, pero es a la hora de recibir o enviar datos que los recibo con coma al igual para enviárselos tengo que transformarlos a coma o si no me indica que el número no es válido,

Comment: Con `phpinfo()`revisa el valor de `date.timezone`.

Comment: Si estaban diferente pero lo corregí en mi ambiente de pruebas pero sigue pasando lo mismo.

Comment: ALTER SESSION SET NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '.,' corriendo esta sentencia al crear la conexión se corrigió el problema, gracias de igual forma.

Comment: Joaquin, aunque haya pasado mucho tiempo, debes poner tu resolución del problema _como respuesta_ y [aceptarla](/help/accepted-answer).